# Ender 3 printing fails with several Cura profiles

Tags: creality-ender-3, ultimaker-cura, pla

I have just purchased the Creality Ender 3 Printer and tried to print the model that comes with it on the SD card and the print was completed successfully with amazing quality details. So far, so good. After that, I downloaded Cura 3D printing software and installed it on my machine, and then tried to slice a model that I had just made with Fusion 360.

On the first try, I chose the standard quality Cura profile and saved it to the printer to print it but the print failed in the way the uploaded video. After playing around with some settings and trying to use some of the profiles that I found online, the same case with each new profile so I came across an idea if there is a way to extract the settings from the G-code file within the printer SD card and use to print the new 3D model.

Is there a way to extract the profile settings from in my case the `cat3.5h.gcode` file?

Or any other working solution for my problem such as a good cura profile to print with PLA filament

[Video of print failure](https://streamable.com/p22shx)

Comment: So, the default models print fine, also after all your efforts changing it to print your own models? It seems your offset it wrong, it does not home correctly, what has changed between the SD card model prints and the printing of your own models?

Comment: The video is not viewable anymore, please re-upload and take screenshots so that you can support the video once it is not available anymore.

Answer (score 2):

That is not your Cura settings, it's just because your nozzle is too high off the print bed.

Any profile you use will fail unless you correct the nozzle height. Look up instructions for bed levelling on an Ender 3. It's pretty easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

As the question is specifically asking for profile settings and not the problem with the Z-offset, this answer addresses the question at hand:

> Is there a way to extract the profile settings from in my case the `cat3.5h.gcode` file?

No, you cannot get the profile settings from the G-code file.

But, looking at the video, your nozzle is way too far from the bed. It looks as if the bed is too low (loosen the leveling screws) or lower the Z endstop.

Note that slicer settings in Cura do not affect the distance between the bed and the nozzle (this much as shown in the video), unless:

- You have installed a plugin allowing you to create an extra offset between the bed and the nozzle, or
- your model has not been dropped to the heated bed (unlikely, as this requires you to manually turn this off in the settings).